# building comma-separated file

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to create a comma-separated file using ruby.  The data are coming from a MySQL database.

So an example file would look like:

```
userid, username, firstname, lastname, tags
2343,blankman, blank, man, "hello world tags-here"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a standard CSV library:

> http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html
>      http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html

or FasterCSV:

> http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

which you can use this way:

```
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

or

```
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  my_array.each do |item|
    csv << [item['name'], item['phone_number']]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply output the data from the database into a CSV file directly with something like this:

```
find_by_sql(["SELECT userid, username, firstname, lastname, tags FROM blankman_table INTO OUTFILE ? FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'", filename])
```

Not very sexy, but I've found the MySQL CSV generation is a lot faster than Ruby's FasterCSV library.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rows` is an array of arrays:

```
require 'csv'

comma_separated = CSV.generate {|csv| rows.each {|row| csv << row}}
```